# Need to get an XML from server encoded in windows-1252 for my iOS application

Tags: ios, xml, windows-1252

I have an iOS application which is download from server an XML file encoded in Windows 1252.

I am using the following code to save it to my document folder :

```
NSString *path = @"http://server/file.xml";
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[path stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding]];
    NSData *xmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    if(xmlData == nil) {
        // Error - handle appropriately
        NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }
    NSString *applicationDocumentsDir=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    NSString *storePath=[applicationDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"annonces.xml"];
    [xmlData writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
    NSLog(@"write xml");
```

It doesn't work, I've got an nil response when I try to read it with the parser. How could I do to get it properly. I cannot change the encoding of te xml which is on the server. If I change the XML encoding manually, I've got a correct response.

This is how I pass the XML string to parse it with XML Dictionnary class :

```
NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"annonces.xml"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
    NSDictionary *items = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:string];
    NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", items);
```

Comment: You get the "error exception" where? You don't say which line doesn't work.

Comment: It's not an NPE, I mean, I have an error: xmlData is nil. If I change the encoding of the xml file manually to UTF-8, it works. I need to get this works with Windows 1252 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL variable contains the url address of the location of the XML file you want to download.

However you are applying NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding to the url, not to the content of the file.

xmlData is nil because dataWithContentsOfURL: cannot find the file at the location you have specified within URL.

You need to download the file first, then once its downloaded then you can be concerned about what encoding its in and how to parse it.

The way you are using NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding has got nothing to do with the content of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The fact is, I manage to get the xml, but when I try to get its content, I only got a nil response. If I change the encoding manually, I get the response correctly. I'm using the XMLDictionary class to parse it.

Comment: But your code does't even show anything to do with XMLDictionary!!!!!!  You show the code for getting the XML, not the code for parsing it!!!

Comment: I'm sorry Amino, didm't want to be rude. Here is the code where I get the content of the xml with XMLDictionary : NSString *path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"annonces.xml"];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding error:NULL];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
    NSDictionary *items = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:string];
    NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", items);

Comment: Then your question is not as in the title and originally posted, the question is how to use XMLDictionary with NSWindowsCP1252StringEncodin encoded data. I've never used XMLDictionary so I've no idea. I would a)repost your question to be more specific and accurate b) step through the XMLDictionary code to see where its going wrong c) ask the author of XMLDictionary if it supports this encoding. Its possible it doesn't even support NSWindowsCP1252StringEncodin, in which case you would need to use another XML parser that does.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. a) In fact, I am not clear enough because I encountered two issues: one when downloading I have an error when I try to download the xml with windows 1252 encoding. Then I can't parse it because the string I get is nil. b) I did, it seems you're right it may does not support this encoding which is sad... ^^ I mark your answer as good. I will try to get the file and parse it with others ways.